# Kubuntu stucks on login screen

Tags: kubuntu, pam

Kubuntu stacks on login screen when password is expiried.
it just doesn't show new password fields after password enter.
I know how to change it in another way, but I need change expired password via GUI
The same problem in 22 and 20 kubuntu, but still can't find any answer in internet​.

```
Jun 26 12:31:36 xvlin16 sddm-helper[1005]: [PAM] Starting...
Jun 26 12:31:36 xvlin16 sddm-helper[1005]: [PAM] Authenticating...
Jun 26 12:31:36 xvlin16 sddm-helper[1005]: [PAM] Preparing to converse...
Jun 26 12:31:36 xvlin16 sddm-helper[1005]: [PAM] Conversation with 1 messages
Jun 26 12:31:37 xvlin16 kernel: [ 132.482027] audit: type=1400 audit(1687768297.085:72): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" class="file" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/proc/1005/cmdline" pid=658 comm="sssd_nss" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jun 26 12:31:37 xvlin16 sddm-helper[1005]: [PAM] returning.
Jun 26 12:31:37 xvlin16 sddm-helper[1005]: [PAM] Preparing to converse...
Jun 26 12:31:37 xvlin16 sddm-helper[1005]: [PAM] Conversation with 1 messages
Jun 26 12:31:37 xvlin16 sddm[700]: Authentication error: "You are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)."
Jun 26 12:31:37 xvlin16 sddm-helper[1005]: [PAM] Preparing to converse...
Jun 26 12:31:37 xvlin16 sddm-helper[1005]: [PAM] Conversation with 1 messages
Jun 26 12:31:37 xvlin16 sddm[700]: Authentication information: "Changing password for user2."
Jun 26 12:31:37 xvlin16 sddm-helper[1005]: [PAM] Preparing to converse...
Jun 26 12:31:37 xvlin16 sddm-helper[1005]: [PAM] Conversation with 1 messages
Jun 26 12:31:37 xvlin16 sddm-greeter[789]: Message received from daemon: LoginFailed
```

what I got:
https://i.ibb.co/HgL3zsG/image.png
What I expected to see:
https://ask-ubuntu.ru/images/d35a5670d6890060d4cf4b01ab45c5bc18b04e02.jpg